# how to place an image to center?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I use Action Text. When I place the image to text area, it places right. I don't know how place it to the center.[image]

Comment: Could you please update your question to include your code and describe what you have attempted so far?

Comment: From [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#rendering-rich-text-content): To customize the HTML rendered for embedded images and other attachments (known as blobs), edit the `app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb` template created by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly editable from the editor, so just add some styles:

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/actiontext.css */

.trix-content .attachment img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```